# Backup full drive structure, skipping one partition content

Tags: partition, backup, dd, disk-image

I need to backup laptop drive. But in fact what matters is not data as in my data files kept on laptop but all systems, settings, lvm and in general whole disk structure - partitioning, UUIDs, LUKS etc.

I have here separate data partition (~800gb) which contains only data files (it's not even home, just data directories, which are backed up separately anyways) so I don't want it to be copied into image. I know it's probably necessary to create 1:1 full disk copy to easily put it back on drive, but then I'd like this one partition to be copied as zeroed empty space (then i could compress image pretty effectively with zlib or something). It'd be nice to avoid copying those 800gb rather than copying and then clearing space of this partition but if it's not possible then any solution is acceptable.

Comment: The blockid is related to the hardware device, so I am not sure your backup is useful (at least on some different hardware, e.g. a new disk)

Comment: no this backup is rather meant just for this specific drive.